# toggle check between checkbox in a gridview and validation on button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

1. I have a grid view with template fields with 2 checkbox column and a textbox column. 
   I need javascript to toggle the check status in the checkboxes(i.e I have 2 checkbox with name chkapprove and chkreject, if I check "chkapprove" then "chkreject" should uncheck if it is already checked and vice versa).
2. I need a button click function which has to alert with msg "Enter the reason" when chkreject is checked and nothing is entered in the text box.

```
function reason() 
{
    MyGridView = document.getElementById('<%= grdaccess.ClientID %>');

    var Inputs = MyGridView.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var chkBox = "Chkreject";
    var textbox = "txtreason";

    for (var n = 0; n < Inputs.length; ++n) 
        if (Inputs[n].type == 'checkbox' && Inputs[n].id.indexOf(chkBox, 0) >= 0 && Inputs[n].checked)
            if (Inputs[n].type == 'textbox' && Inputs[n].id.indexOf(textbox, 0) >= 0 && Inputs[n].length <= 0)    
            {
                alert("enter the reason");
                return false;
            }
    return true;
}

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" CssClass="showall" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="javascript:return reason();" onclick="btnsubmit_Click" />
```

this is the code I have written for condition 2 but it's not working.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Thanks in advance,

gowrishankar.

Comment: For #1, why don't you just use grouped radio buttons?

Comment: once selected we can switch between the option but not deselect it. actually i have this grid to approve or reject projects..if there are many project i can approve and reject some and leave the rest.and i hav an adv. of deselecting both checkoxs even after checking it which i think not possible in radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Please copy both aspx and c# code behind files. Then you try to test.

------------- aspx codes ------------------

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebTest._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css" >
        .req
        {
           background-color:Red;
        }
    </style>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var rejArr = new Array(), tmpArr;

        function CheckStatus(txtId, chkAppId, chkRejId, type) {
            if (type == 'A' && document.getElementById(chkAppId).checked) {
                document.getElementById(chkRejId).checked = false;
            }
            else if (type == 'R' && document.getElementById(chkRejId).checked) {
                document.getElementById(chkAppId).checked = false;
                document.getElementById(txtId).focus();
            }

            if (!document.getElementById(chkRejId).checked) {
                document.getElementById(chkAppId).checked = true;
                type = 'A';
            }

            ListOfText(txtId, type);
        }

        function ListOfText(txtId, type) {
            var len = rejArr.length;

            if (type == 'R')
                rejArr[len] = txtId;
            else {
                var idx = 0;
                tmpArr = new Array();

                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    document.getElementById(rejArr[i]).className = "";
                    if (txtId != rejArr[i])
                        tmpArr[idx++] = rejArr[i];
                }

                rejArr = tmpArr;
            }
        }

        function CheckReject() {
            var txtObj;

            if (rejArr.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < rejArr.length; i++) {
                    txtObj = document.getElementById(rejArr[i]);

                    if (txtObj != null && txtObj.value == "") {
                        txtObj.className = "req";
                    }
                }

                alert("Please provide reason of reject.");

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NAME" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Message">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMsg" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Message">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkApp" runat="server" Text="Approve" Checked="true" />
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRej" runat="server" Text="Reject" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return CheckReject();" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

------------c# code behind --------------------------

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

namespace WebTest
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindData();
        }

        private void BindData()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("NAME");

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "James";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "Paul";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "John";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "Williams";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            gv.DataSource = dt;
            gv.DataBind();
        }

        protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                TextBox txtCtrl = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtMsg");

                //get approve check box control
                CheckBox chkApp = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkApp");

                //get reject checkbox control
                CheckBox chkRej = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkRej");

                chkApp.Attributes.Add("onclick", "CheckStatus('" + txtCtrl.ClientID + "','" + chkApp.ClientID + "','" + chkRej.ClientID + "','A')");
                chkRej.Attributes.Add("onclick", "CheckStatus('" + txtCtrl.ClientID + "','" + chkApp.ClientID + "','" + chkRej.ClientID + "','R')");

            }
        }
    }
}
```